# Create array from SQL query

Tags: sql, arrays, wordpress

I am using the following code to pull data from a WordPress SQL database into an array...

```
global $wpdb;
$blogusers = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=seller');

foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    $count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_mymeta1 WHERE value='$user->user_login'");
    $total = $count[0]->count;

    $arrData=array("Seller"=>"$user->user_login","Total"=>"$total");
    $arrRtn=array();
    array_push($arrRtn, $arrData);

    print_r($arrRtn);
}
```

It is returning the following array....

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Seller] => 76 [Total] => 989 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Seller] => 33 [Total] => 765 ) )
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Seller] => 93 [Total] => 743 ) )
```

But I am trying to get the data in an array that looks like this...

```
var $example_data = array(
        array(
            'Seller'    => '76',
            'Total'     => '989'
        ),
        array(
            'Seller'    => '33',
            'Total'     => '765'
        ),
        array(
            'Seller'    => '93',
            'Total'     => '743'
        ),
    );
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Move `$arrRtn=array();` outside (before) the loop, right now you're clearing the result array every iteration and appending to the empty array every time.

Comment: That is giving me three copies of everything

Comment: Does it add 3 copies to the array, or just print it 3 times since you're printing it in a loop that runs 3 times?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I was printing the array inside the loop like you said :)  Each entry in the array is prefixed with a number though, is there a way to lose these?